# What WP-API authentication method should I use to interact with anonymous / not-logged visitors?

Tags: ajax, authentication, wp-api

I am going to track number of plays of a video in my site by both visitors and users. Whenever the video starts playing I am using JavaScript for the event handling in the frontend and write to `wp_options` or `wp_usermeta` to track these interactions.

I was going to make an AJAX request to the `wp_ajax_$action` and `wp_ajax_nonpriv_$action` hooks but I'd like to use this small task as an opportunity to experiment with the new REST API since I heard it is going to replace the old `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` way of doing it on the long run.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [WP REST API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org) use the [permission_callback](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/#permissions-callback) found in the [Adding Custom Endpoints Docs](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/).

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v2', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'args' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => 'is_numeric'
            ),
        ),
        'permission_callback' => function (WP_REST_Request $request) {
            if ( current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
                return true;
            } 
            else { 
                return false;
            }
        }
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: To clarify: since I want all requests to be processed, regardless of the users permissions, I would make the permission callback always return true, correct? `'permission_callback' => '__return_true'`

Comment: Yes, or just leave off `permission_callback'`.